# C# Libnoise 3D Terraingeneration, how to use the getValue() method?

Tags: c#, monogame, terrain

I haven't found any answer right now in this topic.

Currently I'm using Monogame to program my own voxel engine, for beginning with 3D programming.

I have set up a class wich uses ImprovedPerlin, with a MultiFractal filter, now there is my problem, how can I use the value the noise generates? It should be something between -1 and 1, but how do I find out if a solid block or air should be generated?

Hope that my question is clear enough to you guys.